These tags [look] like synonyms
These should all be synonyms of regex-lookarounds (3.3k questions):

regex-look-ahead (37 questions)
positive-lookahead (31 questions)
lookbehind (390 questions)
negative-lookbehind (213 questions)
positive-lookbehind (15 questions)

For the record, here are the existing synonyms:

negative-lookahead
lookahead
lookaround


are those used exclusively or overwhelmingly for regexp questions? I'm asking because lookahead isn't just a thing for regexps, but for all kinds of parsing of all kinds of formal languages, at least upto the context-free ones. -- on the other hand, anyone with knowledge that exceeds regexps (in the formal languages sense) will probably not have a programming problem but a conceptual question, which should go on [cstheory.se] or similar SEs

@ChristophRackwitz [tag:lookahead] is already a synonym. As for [tag:regex-look-ahead] and [tag:positive-lookahead], they are indeed exclusively used for regex questions.

The terminology "zero width assertion" also exists for these.

@KarlKnechtel True, though in my experience that word is also used to describe \b and \B.

Looking at the four tags that do not have regex in their name and searching for questions with that tag while excluding [regex] and [regex-lookarounds] yields a total of 11 questions, of which a single one appears to not be about common regex.

Are people actively answering any of these questions? The top are also the top of the regex tag, which is not a good thing. It means that they don't specialize on these.

tiny numbers of watchers on most of those. the value and importance of the tags seems low.

These tags [look] like synonyms

Personally, I'm not sure lookaheads/lookbehinds should be synonymized, even though we already have one such synonym. From a regex + VBA standpoint I actually cannot do lookbehinds (not supported in the language) while I can do lookaheads. They are different constructs with different language support.

@ErikA yes, also even if they are both supported, there are usually different restrictions. In a lot of regex flavours a lookbehind must be a known size. So, you can't look behind for something like (?<=x\d+) (letter "x" before a bunch of digits) but you might be able do a variable sized lookahead (e.g., (?=\d+x) for a letter "x" after a bunch of digits).

considering tags to be ways to summon servile creatures, the crowd attracted by lookahead is the same as the crowd attracted by lookbehind. I see no reason not to treat those as synonyms of each other, or something else that expresses the union or slight superset of those terms.

@ChristophRackwitz except that you only need regex to do the same thing.

@InSync I agree, but it seems worthwhile to discuss them in the same breath anyway.
